# I want to make checkboxlist selected based on data return from database and other will be uncheck

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a checkboxlist i have inserted selected item to database.now having problem
to return those item to checkbox and make other item unselected.
My chekboxlist is given below.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Chk_type" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                       CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" RepeatColumns="3" TextAlign="Right">
                       <asp:ListItem>KG School(Bangla Medium)</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>KG School(English Medium)</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Vocational Institute</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Secondary School</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Degree College(With HSC)</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Honors College(With HSC)</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Honors College(Without HSC)</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>University College</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>University</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Polytechnic Institute</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Coaching Center</asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code behind to insert selected item to database is

```
 String str = "";

                 for (int i = 0; i <= Chk_type.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                 {
                 if (Chk_type.Items[i].Selected)
                 {

                 if (str == "")
                 {
                 string sql = @"INSERT INTO institute_type (inst_code,inst_type) VALUES ('" + Txtnst_code.Text + "','" + Chk_type.Items[i].Text + "')";
                 Connstring.insert(sql);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  //  str += Chk_type.Items[i].Text;
                 }
                 }
                 }
                 Response.Write("Your data Sucessfully saved");
                 Chk_type.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

now i want return item will be selected and other will be unselected
to get return item i am using this function

```
 public void bind_checkbox()
 {
     DataTable dt = Connstring.SqlDataTable(@"select version FROM  institute_info WHERE  inst_code = '" + Txtnst_code.Text + "'");
     Check_version.DataSource = dt;
     Check_version.DataTextField = "version";
     Check_version.DataValueField = "inst_code";
     Check_version.DataBind(); 
 }
```

database table structure is
[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MaxSorin I want to make checkboxlist selected based on data return from database and other will be uncheck

Comment: What column in your database table determines if something is selected or not?

Comment: @MaxSorin acually i don't want to do this you are talking about. i have saved selected item to data base with a serial number. now i am calling those item according to that serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is

```
private void bind_checkbox_inst_type()
 {
     string qur = @"SELECT  inst_type FROM    institute_type";
 DataTable dt =Connstring. SqlDataTable(qur);
     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i <= Chk_type.Items.Count - 1; i++)
         {
             foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
             {
                 if (Chk_type.Items[i].Text == dr["inst_type"].ToString().Trim())
                {
                  Chk_type.Items[i].Selected=true ;
                  break;
                }

             }
         }


     }
 }
```